# spring using by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I upgraded rails to 4.1.0 & installed `gem "spring"`

After it, I patched `bundle exec spring binstub --all`. Now, all my `bin/*` includes

```
begin
  load File.expand_path("../spring", __FILE__)
rescue LoadError
end
```

But, if I run, saying `time spring rake -T` & `time rake -T` times 1 second & 3 seconds! It seems that spring not used by default in my application. What's going wrong? It's bad thing that I need to write annoying `spring ..command..` before any rake task, rails server or rspec. What I need to do to avoid `spring` command with spring worked by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to prepend spring everytime.  I'm not sure why you're getting those numbers but try the following.

```
# make sure that spring server is stopped
>> spring stop

# take note of the time here
>> time bin/rake routes

# start spring server
>> spring

# test routes again
>> time bin/rake routes
```

The second `bin/rake routes` should be very fast.  In one of our apps, without spring, it takes 8 seconds to show the routes.  With spring, it's less than a second.

For rspec, you need to install an additional gem for that.  Look at the [additional commands section of the spring gem](https://github.com/rails/spring#additional-commands)

Comment: It seems true, but what about rvm? I don't want to paste bin/rake, I need to print just rake. I tried solutions from the internet, but they don't work. Do you know solution?