# spring & rvm symlink alias commands to bin/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm, spring-gem

I use Rails 4 with `spring` & `spring-commands-rspec` gem. This question have relation to this: [spring using by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234045/spring-using-by-default)

When I run `time rspec` I get something like 5 seconds. If I run `time bin/rspec` I have 2 seconds. 
If I run `time rake -T` I get 3 seconds, if I run `time bin/rake -T` I get less than a second.

Where is the trouble? Why I need to run all commands through `bin/` binstubs to parse them through `spring`. How can I avoid that?

Related issue at github: https://github.com/jonleighton/spring-commands-rspec/issues/17#issuecomment-43174278

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is detailed howto about adding binstubs to path: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki/Understanding-binstubs#adding-project-specific-binstubs-to-path . I think that's better way than @Douglas offered

Answer (score 1):

I avoid that by explicitly calling `spring` before all the commands I run, like `spring rspec spec`, `spring rails c`, `spring rake`. And to make that easier, I aliased `spring` to just `s`. It's kinda impossible to integrate spring right into those binaries because, among many other reasons: RSpec, Rake and Rails binaries are not aware of Spring existence, you can't assume you (and everyone else) always wants to run commands using Spring. You can open those files in your bin folder using you text editor and see what Spring is doing there.